# How to merge 300 files into 3 files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a bunch of files in a folder.  All consist of three different types; three different schemas.  I want to group the files into three types.

1. 'FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR'
2. 'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule CI'
3. 'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule ENT'

I want to save these 300 files as 3 CSV files, based on the file names being similar.

Here are actual file names.

```
FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR 03312001.txt
FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR 03312002.txt
...
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule CI 03312001.txt
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule CI 03312002.txt
...
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule ENT 03312001.txt
FFIEC CDR Call Schedule ENT 03312002.txt
```

I think the problem is with this line:

```
if x in f:
```

Here is the code that I am testing.

```
import os, glob
import pandas as pd

mylist = ['FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR',
        'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule CI',
        'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule ENT']

path = "C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\schemas\\"

all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt"))

all_df = []
for f in all_files: 
    for x in mylist:
        if x in f:
            print(x)
            df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='\t', skiprows=1) 
            df['file'] = os.path.basename(f)
            all_df.append(df) 

df_append = pd.concat(all_df, ignore_index=True, sort=True)
df_append.to_csv("C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\" + x + ".csv")
```

When I run this code, everything is dumped into one single CSV file.  I want three separate CSV files, one for each of the similar/grouped file names. I made some progress, but I couldn't quite figure it out.

Comment: if you think problem is `if x in f:` then why you don't use `print(x, f, x in f)` to check what you have in variables and if `... in ...` gives expected result. If it gives wrong result then you have to use something different. Shortly: use `print()` to debug code. OR learn to use real debuger.

Comment: your problem is because you add all files to the same `all_df.append(df)` - and it has to append all files in one file. Frankly I don't know why you didn't see it. You should use three different lists for this - if `all_POR`, `all_CI`, `all_ENT` and add different files to different lists. And after loop you should run `pd.concat(all_POR).to_csv("POR.csv")`, `pd.concat(all_CI).to_csv("CI.csv")` and `pd.concat(all_ENT).to_csv("ENT.csv")`

Comment: eventually instead of three lists you can use one dictionary with three lists for files - `all_df = {'FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR': [] , 'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule CI' : [], 'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule ENT'; []}` and it should be easier to put files `all_df[x].append(df)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Frankly problem seems so primitive so I don't understand why you have problem</s>

You put all files on the same list

```
all_df.append(df)
```

so finally it has to write all files to one CSV.

You shoudl create three lists for three types of files. Or one dictionary with three list for files

```
all_df = {
    'FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR': [],  # list for files `FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR`
    'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule CI': [], # list for files `FFIEC CDR Call Schedule CI`
    'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule ENT': [], # list for files `FFIEC CDR Call Schedule ENT
}
```

And then you can use `x` to put file to correct list

```
all_df[ x ].append(df)
```

And after `loop` you can use another loop to save three files

```
for x in mylist:
    # use `all_df[x]
    df_append = pd.concat(all_df[x], ignore_index=True, sort=True)
    df_append.to_csv("C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\" + x + ".csv")
```

---

```
import os, glob
import pandas as pd

mylist = [
    'FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR',
    'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule CI',
    'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule ENT'
]

path = "C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\schemas\\"

all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt"))

all_df = {
    'FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR': [],  # list for files `FFIEC CDR Call Bulk POR`
    'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule CI': [], # list for files `FFIEC CDR Call Schedule CI`
    'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule ENT': [], # list for files `FFIEC CDR Call Schedule ENT
}

# --- first loop ---

for f in all_files: 
    for x in mylist:
        if x in f:
            print(x)
            df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='\t', skiprows=1) 
            df['file'] = os.path.basename(f)
            all_df[x].append(df) 

# --- second loop ---

for x in mylist:
    # use `all_df[x]
    df_append = pd.concat(all_df[x], ignore_index=True, sort=True)
    df_append.to_csv("C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\" + x + ".csv")
```

Comment: Sometimes these things are not obvious to me, or I wouldn't ask these questions. My education is in finance, not computer science. I learned what I know by reading some books, scrolling through blogs, Google searches, etc.

Comment: sorry, before writing answer I checked your profile and you have >13000 reputation, >2000 answers, >600 answers for Python so I thought you are more experienced.

Comment: My background is in VBA and SQL. I stumbled upon Python around 2013.  Python is completely different from VBA and SQL.  I know some things in Python, but there's a lot that I don't know.  I wouldn't ask a question here if can figure out a solution by myself.  I got some points by trying to help other people on SO.  I feel like my answers are 100% correct, but a lot of my answers are not up-voted, for some reason.  Thanks again.  That was a huge help and it's gonna save me a lot of time!!!